# Assigning essays in take home exams

Tags: exams

I was talking to a college student I know who is currently taking linear algebra. He told me that during his take home midterm/final exams he was assigned essay questions, which surprised me quite a bit

I believe the one on the midterm had the prompt

> Write a two page essay about the Jordan normal form

Is this common practice? It seems to me that it's testing a lot of skills which are not really related to what most linear algebra classes set out to teach. Does anyone know of any references which argue for this as a good examination method?

Comment: In the age of ChatGPT, I would say that such a vague prompt on a take home exam is a bad idea.

Comment: @Aeryk That's definitely true and not an angle I'd considered. Even for students who aren't cheating though, I'm having trouble seeing the value in this compared to a series of exercises which demonstrate an application or something.

Comment: Asking students to "write in the discipline" is a moderately common practice (I am not sure that it is a *standard* practice anywhere, but there has been a push over the last 20 years, at least, to get students to write more).  Essay prompts on final examinations might be a part of that.  Though *this prompt* leaves a lot to be desired (in my opinion).  Too vague, no real direction for the students, etc.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Hopefully you will expand that comment (elaborating on the first sentence with reference to mathematics education) into an answer!

Comment: @ryang It is a comment because I don't really have the time right now to do the research on WIC and WAD, nor to look up any relevant stats on the topic (it's finals week; I'm swamped).  As such, I don't really have time to put a real answer together.  Anyone else is free to run with what I've started.

Comment: Even half a year ago, this would have been a good way to help prevent the cheating available through so many other sources.